# After creating a stored procedure and querying the table created,returns 'Invalid object name' even after successful creation of the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I had written and successfully created a stored procedure by the query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Table_Load] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    DECLARE @Row_Count_Inserted BIGINT 

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DBB.dbo.Table;

    SELECT * 
    INTO DBB.dbo.Table
    FROM
        (SELECT * 
         FROM DBB.dbo.customer_table) y

    SET @Row_Count_Inserted = @@RowCount

    SELECT @Row_Count_Inserted Row_Count_Inserted
END
```

This shows that the stored procedure is created and is present in the database. But when I query the table 'Table' using

```
  SELECT * FROM DBB.dbo.Table
```

I get an error

> Invalid object name

How can I solve this issue? I have refreshed the database as well but it does not work.

Comment: Why are you using 3 part naming to reference an object in the same database? As for your problem, clearly the table does *not* exist; a procedure is not validates until you execute it, so if you reference a table that doesn't exist, the procedure will be created without issue.

Comment: So i would have to create an empty table first in the database and then execute the Stored Procedure?

Comment: No you don't need to create the table. Your procedure will create it.

Comment: Your procedure code will work fine. It is a bit more complicated than it needs to be but it works fine.

Comment: But why is the table not being created in the database?

Comment: Did you execute your procedure? Or just create it? exec Table_Load

Comment: I executed it. The procedure exists and can be seen in the database but the table that was supposed to be created does not. SP- Table_load, Table it was supposed to create- Table.

Comment: Then your procedure is not the same code you posted here.

Comment: Creating the procedure does not mean executing it, @Ambreen . It sounds like your `CREATE`d it but haven't `EXECUTE`d it.

Comment: Oh wait a minute....when you say the table doesn't exist how do you know that? Is it because the last query to select from the newly created table has red underlines in SSMS and the tooltip say invalid object name? That is because intellisense would need to be refreshed. ctrl + shirt + r

Comment: Yes it shows red underlines in SSMS and the tooltip say invalid object, but i have already refreshed it.

Comment: Try selecting from the table. Or query sys.tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your procedure greatly simplified to remove a lot of extra code. Assuming you have the table customer_table this will work just fine.

```
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Table_Load] As
Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    drop table If Exists dbo.MyTable;

    Select * 
    into MyTable
    from customer_table

    select Row_Count_Inserted = @@RowCount
End

GO

exec Table_Load

GO

select * from MyTable
```